# Why to use NSData to Json

Tags: json, nsdata

Every time I make a call to Json, I need to use NSData and Json.deserialize.
Since Json is just a string, why cannot I just read it through rest and then use it at the other side, without using NSData, Json.Serialization, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a method for sending data through strings (not binary). Using as a string is possible, but you'd have to parse it yourself:

Here's a JSON string:

```
"{\"test\": \"foo\"}"
```

and it can be converted to

```
{test: "foo"}
```

and used like a Hash/Dictionary.

I mean, you can't get the use a string as a dictionary, can you?

```
"Nope.".get("Nope")
```

Answer (score -1):

JSON is not a string. JSON is a binary format. That binary format is human readable but it's not a string. That's why we have to use `NSData` and why we have tools for JSON encoding and decoding instead of creating JSON data by appending strings together.

Comment: Actually, JSON **is** a string... NBT is the binary equivalent of JSON, though

Comment: @penne12 Only in the same sense as XML. Converting it to string already loses some information (e.g. encoding). There is a reason why we are using `application/json` instead of the older `text/json`.